# VBA Problems with Concatenating String

Tags: vba, concatenation

I am trying to assign each of the ID's you see in column E and F of `ws4` here...

[image]

...to the respective ID on my `wsOutput` in column K and L, respectively.

[image]

My code runs through without an Error but nothing happens. This is one of my first projects, so I apologize if this is straight-forward question.

I also consulted the Internet and found:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8/how-to-concatenate-multiple-rows-by-the-condition/fdd048ba-5405-4e53-b463-125f9cde2c0c?auth=1
- http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=12298

However, I wasn't able to get their approaches working.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
'Previous Code
'wsOutput -> Filter Sheet - Worksheet (TARGET) ; ws4 = Search Skills - Worksheet (SOURCE)
Dim separator As String, PreviousResultCG As String, NewResultCG As String, PreviousResultCategory As String, NewResultCategory As String

If separator = "" Then separator = " , "

'lRowInput = ws4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row - from above
lRowOutput = wsOutput.Range("A4:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row


With ws4

    'For each ID on the Source-Worksheet
    For Each ID In .Range("A2:A" & lRowInput)

        'Find the respective ID on Target-Worksheet
        Set FindID = wsOutput.Range("A4:A" & lRowOutput).Find(what:=ID, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

        'Get all CG ID's for the supplier and add them to previously found ID's of that supplier
        If FindID = ID Then

            PreviousResultCG = wsOutput.Range("K" & FindID.row).value

            NewResultCG = PreviousResultCG & separator & .Range("E" & ID.row)

            wsOutput.Range("K" & ID.row).value = NewResultCG


            PreviousResultCategory = wsOutput.Range("L" & FindID.row).value

            NewResultCategory = PreviousResultCategory & separator & .Range("F" & ID.row)

            wsOutput.Range("L" & FindID.row).value = NewResultCategory

        End If

    Next ID

End With
```

Comment: I bet this is XL? Why not just use VLOOKUP?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is Excel, yes. I wouldn't know how vlookup would solve my problem. However, as I hinted above, I am a beginner in VBA.

Comment: [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) is a built-in function in Excel which will allow you to do what you describe above. Unless there are other requirements you need to meet, I suggest you try the built-in function first.

Comment: What do you mean with "other requirements" ? My only Problem is that the Input-Worksheet is not fixed but rather get's re-populated when a Button is clicked. Also: The number of entries will vary every time. That's why I tried to automate it.

Comment: Oh, and VLOOKUP does not put all the different ID's into one cell, right?

Comment: You write the values on the output sheet in the rows numbers of the source sheet. (`ID.Row` instead of `FindID.Row`) Maybe they are added but you don't see them?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Thank you for pointing that out. I corrected it and still, no error, nothing happens. The sample-data is not large enough to cause me not seeing this though. I re-checked right now.

Comment: No, VLOOKUP doesn't do that. You said you need the result in K and L right?

Comment: Yes, ws4 column E to wsOutput column K and ws4 column F to wsOutput column L.

Comment: Why isnt Vlookup working for you? I didn't understand. You can bring to K and L columns matched values with the ID's. What is the thing vlookup cant do for you?

Comment: @alisrn VLOOKUP can't concatenate all matched values into one cell, or can it? Looking on my Images above, I would Need (on wsOutput) for each ID - for instance - in column K "1, 2, 3" and in column L "1A, 1B, 2C, 3A,..."

Comment: =concatenate(vlookup(...), ",", vlookup(...)) could work.

Comment: Fist of all, thank you for your time. Could you give me an example for one line for the question at Hand? For instance for the first ID and the Commodity Group in columns E and K, respectively

Comment: I guess I didnt fully understand you. can you add an image about what it should be like at the end for one or two rows?

Comment: My apologies for not making myself clear enough. Here you go: http://imgur.com/a/OTXUj - - Find the Output IDs (column A; they are unique) on the Inputsheet (also column A; where you can have them multiple times) and get the unique CG & Category IDs. All columns are as in the Pictures above.

Answer (score 1):

Place source data in sheet named "source" and create another sheet where you want to lookup values from source data named as "target". Keep columns as you shown in images.

paste below mentioned code in module.

```
Sub look_values()

Dim id, source_id As Range
Dim data_row_num, id_row_num As Long
Dim source_sheet, target_sheet As Worksheet
Dim cg, cat As String

Set source_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("source")
Set target_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("target")
Set id = target_sheet.Range("A2")

Do Until id.Value = ""

    source_sheet.Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    Set source_id = Range("A:A").Find(what:=id.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    On Error Resume Next
    cg = Cells(source_id.Row, 5).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    cat = Cells(source_id.Row, 6).Value
    target_sheet.Activate
    Cells(id.Row, 11).Value = cg
    Cells(id.Row, 12).Value = cat
    Set id = id.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Before running the macro, make sure that the format of ID column on both sheets are same. Will suggest you to First Clean & Trim the ID Column. Because it is visible in the image that ID column in target sheet has unrecognized characters.